# Using INDIRECT to refer to a cell range within a COUNTIFS/SUMIF(S) formula (Error occuring)

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs, excel-indirect

The below formula works, I am trying to change this using INDIRECT to be able to change the cell ranges so it can be updated easier.

`=SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!L2:L344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!N2:N344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!P2:P344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!R2:R344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!T2:T344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!V2:V344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!X2:X344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!Z2:Z344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!AB2:AB344)`

I want to substitute out the `['Other materials'!B2:B344]` and `['Other materials'!X2:Y344)]` and be able to edit the ranges using this `[=INDIRECT("'" & B6 & "'!" & B7 & ":" & B8)]`

I tried to do this, but the answers came out as `#VALUE!` for the `COUNTIFS` and 130206 instead of 122 for the `SUMIF`.

`SUMIF where substituted:=SUMIF((INDIRECT("'" & B6 & "'!" & B7 & ":" & B8)), "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!L2:L344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!N2:N344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!P2:P344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!R2:R344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!T2:T344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!V2:V344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!X2:X344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!Z2:Z344)+SUMIF('Other materials'!B2:B344, "*Germany*", 'Other materials'!AB2:AB344)`

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong and help me get it to work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The values used in the INDIRECT formula are B6 = Other materials (The work sheet on which the data resides), B7 = 2 (The row on which data starts, this shouldn't change), B8 = 344 (The row on which data ends, this will change as things are added.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the column as well, because considering your explanation:

"the values used in the INDIRECT formula are B6 = Other materials (The work sheet on which the data resides), B7 = 2 (The row on which data starts, this shouldn't change), B8 = 344"

your formula looks like: "Other materials'!2:344"

So the values should be: B7 = "B2" and B8="B344", for example

Comment: Is there way to edit my INDIRECT formula to point to the cell with the 'Other materials' sheet, as I need to use the same range for calculating studd residing in other columns on the 'Other materials' worksheet?

Comment: you can use the INDIRECT(ADDRESS()) formula to define dynamically the cell you are pointing to

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89